# Google Photo Sphere Camera Feature

Tags: ios, xcode, camera, photosphere

I'm developing an iOS app for 360 panorama like the street view app made by Google, I want to developed the camera feature but I haven't find any resources or help.

How the logic behind the camera is?

How the dot are displayed on the screen?

Please I really need some help about the logic behind the app.

Comment: thank you. I need same feature as you worked on do you find anything?

Comment: Hello, sorry i haven't find anything , if i find something i will let you know

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this [project](https://github.com/robbykraft/Panorama) on github you can get a clear picture of the 360 degree photo's

You need to process the images into a equirectangular image

Comment: he include a camera feature(take photo with camrea) ot i have to select photo from my gallery??

Comment: Yo have to stich your photos manually using OpenCVSwiftStitch visit the below listed links you can get a clear picture [OpenCVSwiftStitch](https://github.com/foundry/OpenCVSwiftStitch),    [OpenCVStitch](https://github.com/foundry/OpenCVStitch),    [360CamCode](https://github.com/Open360cam/360CamCode)

Comment: i mean it can allow the user to take photo from his phone??

Comment: @Aravind I need to capture same like google street view capture the sphere. Can this [project](https://github.com/robbykraft/Panorama) does same?